# Trying to play Media, app crashes

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

This is the block of code I am trying to execute when the app crashes.

```
    bsharks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){ 
            if (ducks.isPlaying()) {
                ducks.stop();
                ducks.prepareAsync();
                ducks.seekTo(0);
            }
            else{
                ducks = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sharks);
                ducks.start();
            }
        }
    });
```

And the log cat (full name blocked out).
[image]

Comment: The first time you click on the button, I suppose that your mediaPlayer object is not created yet. It is?

Comment: Before your onClick make sure you have initialized your `MediaPlayer`

Comment: Move this `ducks = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sharks);` out of if else or in `onCreate`

Comment: ducks.isPlaying() here ducks might be null. So create MediaPlayer object before doing so or check if(ducks != null){ducks.isPlaying().........

Answer (score 2):

Change your code like the below

```
MediaPlayer ducks = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sharks);
bsharks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){ 
            if (ducks.isPlaying()) {
                ducks.stop();
                ducks.prepareAsync();
                ducks.seekTo(0);
            }
            else{

                ducks.start();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to create `Mediaplayer` object before we using that object.
So create `Mediaplayer` object in `onCreate` method of An actvity. Place following line in `onCreate`.

```
    ducks = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sharks);
```

and put remaining code in button's `onClick` event as follows.

```
bsharks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){            
    if (ducks.isPlaying()) {
            ducks.stop();
            ducks.prepareAsync();
            ducks.seekTo(0);
        }
    else
        {   
            ducks.start();
        }
    }
 });
```